# Сравнительный оборот

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли обособлять сравнительный оборот "как члене ВТО" в следующем предложении?

В Российской Федерации, как члене ВТО, требования технических регламентов и процедур оценки (подтверждения) соответствия должны применяться равным образом для товаров отечественных производителей и импортируемых товаров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Обособленное приложение может присоединятся с союзом как (с дополнительным значением причинности). Т.е.  ***поскольку*** Российская федерация является членом ВТО. 
Справочник по правописанию и стилистике. Розенталь, Д.Э.